# Which Office desktop versions are required to work with Office 365?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

My friend uses Office 2007 and cannot get `open in Excel` links to work on her PC.

My question is which versions of desktop Microsoft Office are supported by such Office 365?

Answer (score 1):

I found it via my google search ["what office version required to work with office online"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=what%20office%20version%20required%20to%20work%20with%20office%20online) and get the result as a microsoft page [here](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Office-365-system-requirements-719254c0-2671-4648-9c84-c6a3d4f3be45).

So that means Office 2010  and 2013 is supported as long as they are in `main stream support` valid dates - 5 years is the common valid time for each version.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft also provides information about this:
https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-business-premium

> Office 365 Business Premium supports Windows Vista and Windows XP for most web-based functionality. However, it does not support the download and use of the latest version of Office software, and you cannot substitute Office 2010 for the latest version. You can connect your existing Office 2010 or Office 2007 software to the Office 365 service, but if you are running Windows Vista or Windows XP, you cannot install Office 365 Business Premium software, and you cannot replace Office 365 Business Premium software with a download of Office 2010.